# CSS Style Header w/Hyperlink Issue

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Below is my basic css style. I have made my "Title" a hyperlink so visitors can quickly get back to the home page. However, when I add my table, the title hyperlink becomes disabled.

```css
/* JavaScript */

.header {
 position: absolute;
 height: 85px;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 padding: 1rem;
 background-color: #3399CC;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 100%;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
.wrap {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 24em;
 margin: auto;
}
.content {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
h1:link, a:link {
 color: white;
}
table, td, th {
 border: 10px solid #ffffff;
 text-align: left;
 margin-top: 140px;
}
table {
 border-collapse: initial;
 width: 100%;
}
td {
 padding: 15px;
 width: 25%;
 line-height: 2;
}
th {
 background-color: grey;
 color: white;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 25%;
}
td:hover {
 background-color: #f5f5f5
}
```

Here is my Title, if I remove the below content my Title stays a hyperlink. If I add the below content, my title stops being a hyperlink.

```html
<body>
<div class="header">
  <h1><a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none">Title</h1>
  </a> </div>
<!-- Here is my table content. -->
<div class="content">
<table class="ex1">
  <tr>
    <th>$company</th>
    <th>$company</th>
    <th>$company</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="ateam.jpg" alt="team" style="width: 260px; 
        height: 150px;"> <br>
      <b>URL:</b> $url <br>
      <b>Location:</b> $location <br>
      <b>Inductry:</b> $dropdown <br>
      <b>Start Date:</b> $sdate  &nbsp <b>End Date:</b> $edate <br>
      <b>Announcement:</b><br>
      $announcement <br></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
<footer></footer>
</body>
```

I can't figure out why adding a table would affect my "Title". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your table top margin overlays the header area, masking the title from the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong order of closing tags here:

```
<h1><a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none">Title</h1></a>
```

That should be

```
<h1><a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none">Title</a></h1>
```

Also, the complete `footer` should be inside the `body`, plus you have no closing tag for `<div class="content">` (i.e. the state before someone else edited the code in your question)

ADDITION / COMPLETE SOLUTION:

Your `.content` was overlaying the `header` (both of which have absolute position). If you erase the `margin: 140px` from the table and move it to the `content` rule, it works:

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
  height: 85px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #3399CC;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 24em;
  margin: auto;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
h1:link,
a:link {
  color: white;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 140px;
}
table,
td,
th {
  border: 10px solid #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
}
table {
  border-collapse: initial;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 25%;
  line-height: 2;
}
th {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 25%;
}
td:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1><a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none">Title</a></h1>
  </div>
  <!-- Here is my table content. -->
  <div class="content">
    <table class="ex1">
      <tr>
        <th>$company</th>
        <th>$company</th>
        <th>$company</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="ateam.jpg" alt="team" style="width: 260px; 
        height: 150px;">
          <br>
          <b>URL:</b> $url
          <br>
          <b>Location:</b> $location
          <br>
          <b>Inductry:</b> $dropdown
          <br>
          <b>Start Date:</b> $sdate &nbsp <b>End Date:</b> $edate
          <br>
          <b>Announcement:</b>
          <br>$announcement
          <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: While what you say is true, it does not answer the question.

Comment: @Alohci Please note the addition to my answer, including the complete solution.

Comment: @ Johannes Thank you, that worked perfectly, except for one part which doesn't make sense sine it works in your "Run Code Snippet." When I made the updates you suggested to Note++ and run it, it keeps the title black and not white. I added `h1:visit, a:visit { color: white;` thinking it would solve the issue especially after someone clicks on it. No luck. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Could it be that it was black only after you had already clicked it once? Then you are on the right track, but it's `a:visited`, not `a:visit`... (BTW you could change that selector to `h1 a:link'  and `h1 a:visited`, no need to have two selectors (h1 is not the link)

Comment: That is what I thought too. I found this and it worked. `<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1><a href="index.html " style="text-decoration : none; color : #ffffff;">Title</a></h1>
  </div>` Thanks for all your help with this one.

Answer (score 0):

I have just run your code in browser and I believe the reason why the link is not working is because `div.content` is actually (invisibly) covering `div.header` therefore preventing the user from hovering over it/clicking it.

The solution I found was changing `div.content` from having `position:absolute;` to `position:relative;`.